# Open Windows Powershell as different user

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

Is it possible to run `powershell.exe` with startup parameters? Specifically I am looking to create a Windows Terminal profile which will launch a Windows Powershell session as a different user (my admin account). Here is a portion of my profile. Ideally, I am looking to modify the `commandline` argument but I am open to alternative workarounds.

[profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIRcG.png)

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer I know, but with respect to the specific requirement:

> launch a Windows Powershell session as a different user

You can achieve this with

`Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential “domain\username” -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList “Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb runAs”`

Comment: YES YES.. but if you want to spawn as a specific user, I think you need "RunAsUser" instead of RunAs.  I also found some neat tricks I didn't know under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989750/running-powershell-as-another-user-and-launching-a-script) post.

Comment: Not quite. I cannot use `Start-Process` from within my profile. This [link](https://superuser.com/questions/747684/how-can-i-run-an-application-with-arguments-from-windows-explorer) is similar to how I would call it from a profile.