# Shortcut created with Batch To Exe Converter stays in memory

Tags: batch, batch-file

I have created several .exe shortcuts on my drive using Batch To Exe Converter for ease of access. ([See "Integrating non-portable apps into the PortableApps Platform"](https://superuser.com/a/1185988/358766))

So for example, to make a shortcut to git-gui, I made the following batch `.bat` file, then converted it to an exe using [Batch To Exe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php).

```
cd cmd & git-gui.exe
```

The issue is that the `.exe` shortcut seems to stay in memory even after the main program closes. As a result, I can't safely eject my drive due to it being "in use". Why won't my shortcut exit once it's done running?

[image: Shortcut running in memory after running]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMD shortcut is waiting for your main program to exit. You need to use the `start` command to run it instead.

```
cd cmd & start git-gui.exe
```

Source: [Why won't cmd exit after execution of batch file?](https://superuser.com/a/192572/358766)