# Add apps stored in subfolders to the PortableApps.com Platform

Tags: portable-apps

Some portable applications store their .exe files in a subdirectory. For instance, [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/) stores [git-gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) under `\PortableGit\cmd\git-gui.exe`. I'd like to be able to launch this app from the [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/) Platform menu.

**How can I run a program stored in a subfolder from the PortableApps.com Platform?**

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I [modified instructions from How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/109788/how-to-create-shortcuts-to-programs-on-usb-drives/) to create an `.exe` shortcut in the program's root folder.

- Download and save your application to `X\PortableApps\ProgramName`
- Open a text editor (such as Notepad) and enter the command `cd <relative app path> & start <app.exe>`. ('start' ensures the script [exits properly](https://superuser.com/a/192572/358766))

  - Example: The command for [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) 64bit would be `cd bin/64bit & start obs64.exe`, while the command for git-gui would be `cd cmd & start git-gui.exe`
- Save your script as a `.bat` file
- *(Optional)*: Extract the icon `.ico` file from your program to use as an icon for your shortcut
- Convert your `.bat` into a `.exe` using [Bat To Exe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php)

  - In the program, browse for your `.bat` batch file with the `...` button
  - Select your program's root folder for the "Save as" location
  - Select the "Invisible" option in the Visibility box to run without opening a console window
  - *(Optional)*: Choose a `.ico` icon in the `Versioninformations` tab under "Icon file"
- Click compile to generate your `.exe` shortcut

Answer (score 0):

With Vivaldi as an example, I was able to make it appear on PortableApps menu with a symbolic link. I think other programs would work as well:

```
cd "E:\PortableApps\Vivaldi"
mklink "vivaldi.exe" "E:\PortableApps\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe"
```