# Why does CTRL-C on "Terminate batch job" prompt means "carry on"?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Our application uses 3 databases, one with client data, and two with configuration data. To prevent destroying client data, the batch file that deletes the client database has first a warning message, and then a pause.

I just called the **delete client database** on my machine *by accident* (no loss; it was just a copy), and when the pause prompt came, I just pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Instead of directly terminating, Windows asked me if I want to **Terminate batch job**.

So I just pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> again because, IMO, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> means **Do NOT carry on**, and because I still had my fingers on those keys anyway.  The batch file just carried on and deleted the database anyway (Meaning I need to restore it, making my PC unusable for two hours).

Why does Windows `CMD.EXE` thinks that when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the **Terminate batch job** prompt, that means that I actually want to carry on (in other words, why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in this context means **Y**, rather then **N**)?

In Linux, the shell actually does what you are asking it, which is to terminate the script without asking a pointless question.  Nobody ever presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in a DOS box by accident (unless they thought they were in a text editor, rather then a DOS box).

Comment: I think its a simple as CTRL+C has cancelled the "prompt"!

Comment: as @cjb110 says the CTRL+C has cancelled the program that is showing the prompt or the batch file that is showing it to you. If you have batch files calling other batch files it may only cancel the child one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two levels of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>:

1. level of any .exe file running in the foreground, which can or not stop its work
2. second level is .bat file from which you run .exe files

Third level would be the cmd.exe itself.

The problem here is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> goes through both levels and in effect you are asked if you want to stop the batch file (level 2), so if you say <kbd>Y</kbd> - you batch file will be immediately terminated. If you say <kbd>N</kbd> what can happen is batch file will continue its run from next command.

Comment: So, it's like the "prompt" asking me if it should terminate the batch file in Windows is a "program", and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> again, I just kill that program, rather than the batch file itself. Idk if actually works like that, but at least the behavior would make sense.

Comment: @SebastienDiot yes, exactly. And to be specific - the prompt is from `cmd.exe` running your `.bat` file.