# Launch cygwin input shell to handle Ctrl+C without "Terminate batch job" prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cygwin

In general, a Windows user [cannot launch a batch file](https://superuser.com/a/35701/45163) and [suppress the `Terminate batch job (Y/N)` prompt on `Ctrl+C`](https://superuser.com/q/35698/45163) without some serious workarounds or limitations.

But, I am wondering with a [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) shell (**bash**) in particular, can I launch it in such a way as to handle `Ctrl+C` without encountering the `Terminate batch job (Y/N)` prompt on the exit of the shell.

Perhaps, if launching it via a batch file [necessarily causes that prompt](https://superuser.com/a/35701/45163) on `Ctrl+C`, then does an effective way to launch it exist outside of a batch file? I know that the Cygwin.bat file does configure some variables, so I would prefer to be able to configure similar variables with another workaround.

I would like a general answer, but I am using the [ConsoleZ wrapper](https://github.com/cbucher/console) to contain the terminal session(s), so I would give more weight to answers that work within this framework.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `Cygwin.bat` file invokes the shell (`bash --login -i` in my instance), so why not invoke the shell directly? So, however you launched the batch file, launch the **bash** executable instead.

In **ConsoleZ**, this means that for your Tab (in the *Tabs* section), set the *Shell* parameter to the location of your `bash.exe` file, instead of your `Cygwin.bat` file. But, don't forget to set your parameters (e.g. `--login -i`) in that *Shell* field as well. Thankfully, **ConsoleZ** has an *Environment* tab in your *Tabs* section, where you can also set additional environment variables, as necessary.