# How to suppress Windows batch job termination confirmation?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

When a Windows batch job has launched a program (executable), the user may press Ctrl-C to stop the program.

This causes Windows batch job to show "Terminate batch job (Y/N)" prompt and to wait for key presses.

How can I suppress this prompt and the need to press any key?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the suggestion by @KTaTk, so long as you clobber the return code in the conditional, it will suppress the "Terminate batch job (Y/N)" prompt.

My workaround is:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
program.exe & set SAVEDRC=!ERRORLEVEL! & call;
echo Return Code was %SAVEDRC%
exit /b %SAVEDRC%
```

Note that it is necessary to use `!ERRORLEVEL!` (delayed expansion) to get the value in the same compound statement, since `%ERRORLEVEL%` (parse-time expansion) does not reflect the updated return code from the program.

Then the `call;` function resets the error level to 0 before the next line is executed.

Finally (optionally), we exit with the saved return code. If it's -1073741510 (`STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT`) and the parent process is also cmd shell, then the parent process will show that prompt.

---

Alternatively, it seems the ctrl-c prompt only happens if it's another process's return code causing that exit code. So creating a *function* which simply exits without changing the ERRORLEVEL will suppress the prompt as well:

```
program.exe & call:ignoreCtrlC
echo Return Code was %ERRORLEVEL%
goto:eof
:ignoreCtrlC
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) in the command that launches the executable:

```
my_executable.exe && exit 0 || exit 1
```

This suppresses any prompting and exits the batch job with code 0 or 1, depending on the exit code of the executable.

This works both for Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Break.

Comment: This is related to [this superuser.com question](https://superuser.com/questions/35698/how-to-supress-terminate-batch-job-y-n-confirmation).

Answer (score 0):

Given that CTRL-BREAK or CTRL-C already is a keypress, you may be looking for an answer that stops a batch script without the requirement to press CTRL-C or CTRL-BREAK.

This answer is in case that is your goal.

In Batch, you can use labels and IF statements to jump around in your script.

For example:

```
    @echo off

::  -- Lets print something to the screen.
    echo This is a test before the loop starts

::  -- Lets set a counter variable to 0, just to be sure.
    set counter=0
    
::  -- Set loop beginning point
:begin

::  -- Increase the counter by one but don't display the result to the screen
    set /a counter=counter+1 >nul
    
::  -- now, write it to the screen our way.
    echo Progress: %counter% of 10
    
::  -- pause the script for a second but without any displaying...
    ping localhost -n 2 >nul
    
::  -- see if we reached 10, if so jump to the exit point of the script.
    if %counter%==10 goto exit
    
::  -- if we reached this point, we have not jumped to the exit point.
::  -- so instead, lets jump back to the beginning point.
::  -- identation is used so the loop clearly stands out in the script
goto begin
    
::  -- set exit point for this script
:exit

::  -- lets print a message. We don't have to, but its nice, right?
    echo End of the script has been reached.
```

This produces the following output, assuming we wrote c:\temp\counter.cmd:

```
c:\temp>counter
This is a test before the loop starts
Progress: 1 of 10
Progress: 2 of 10
Progress: 3 of 10
Progress: 4 of 10
Progress: 5 of 10
Progress: 6 of 10
Progress: 7 of 10
Progress: 8 of 10
Progress: 9 of 10
Progress: 10 of 10
End of the script has been reached.
```