# Start a batch script in job object and kill all processes created inside the job when the batch terminates?

Tags: windows, batch

I have a batch script which gets run on a Windows-based Jenkins node (meaning headless, **no [GUI] windows involved**). The batch script already has its standard input incapacitated by way of `< NUL`, [so as to avoid the "Terminate batch job (Y/N)" prompt.](https://superuser.com/q/35698)

The batch script performs some preparations and ultimately calls a Bash script running either in Cygwin or MSYS2 (depends on the node). From there many new processes are created, other Bash scripts invoked, other batch scripts invoked etc.

**Question:** Is there a way, from the command line -- namely `cmd.exe` --, to create [a job object](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects) to "herd" the processes created by the initial batch script and processes created by those in turn ...?

The goal here is to tear down all processes in the job forcibly -- much like would be done if processes in a job exceed resource quotas -- as soon as the initial script terminates (whichever way!).

**Alternatively:** If `cmd.exe` is too limited, what other utilities onboard a "standard" Windows 10/11 installation can facilitate this?

PS: Process Explorer from Microsoft/Sysinternals has a feature called "Kill Process Tree". This is approximately what I'd need. Alas, the "process tree" is not a reliable mechanism either way. It relies on matching parent PIDs inside the children and there is simply no guarantee that parents outlive their children and semantics differ quite a bit from Unix, too.

Comment: Is it possible to launch all tasks via one program launcher that you write? This program can "tag" its processes for later termination.

Comment: Roughly this would be what the job object achieves. But I want to avoid reinventing the wheel. When searching "job" there is a lot of noise in the context with batch files, so my hope is/was that someone knows a ready solution.

Answer (score 0):

From a CMD, you can use the command `title` to rename the title of that window.

For example, you can set the title as follows: `title kill me later`

You would want to do this for every process that is being spawned.
You can create a batch file that first changes the title and then starts another program if you have to.

Later in your batch script, you can now query these windows using:

```
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq kill me later"
```

and if you like what you see, you can terminate it using:

```
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq kill me later" /F
```

which will close every window that has the title `kill me later`

the `/f` switch will forcefully close the window. Ommitting this parameter will try to close it, but may give a prompt whether or not you want to close the window.

Do note, cmd cannot close itself this way. It will simply not find the window.

[image]

Also, if you use Windows Terminal, and you spawn a CMD instance inside, using this method will not just close that CMD instance, but it will close the entire Windows terminal instance.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. You are assuming there is a window involved. There is not. This runs headlessly and inside a service (as would be expected of a Jenkins node). Adjusted that in the question, because I did not anticipate this. As a side note, this still wouldn't solve the issue, just es "Kill Process Tree" doesn't. Merely killing the process with a particularly titled window is technically no different than just killing the initial `cmd.exe`. But it won't kill any child or grandchild (etc.) processes _reliably_. Thus the job object in my question.

Comment: I indeed am not fully up to date with jenkins so I indeed assumed there would be an identifiable window. If there isn't, then CMD just doesn't have the tools to do this. Other tools like powershell can get information from the spawned process, and gets it process id, but I don't know if that still is the case for a jenkins instance.

Because others may not use a jenkins node, they may be able to use this information, so I won't remove the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to create a user account that is
dedicated to that task.

The initial batch script can then be launched RunAs this
user account, which means that all subsequent child tasks
will also be running under the same user account.

Killing all the tasks can then be done via :

```
taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq user-account-name"
```

This command may need to be run with administrator permissions.