How to disable the prompt "do you want to stop this program (y/N)" when killing program in powershell
I run my program, I enter Ctrl+C, obviously I want to stop the program.
But powershell always asks "do you want to stop the program ? (y/N)".
How can I disable this ? I just want the program to stop without this useless prompt.
EDIT : More details
I have a spring boot app, If I run with java -jar  and I stop it with Ctrl+C, no prompt.
If I run it with "mvn spring-boot:run", then I stop it with Ctrl+C, I get the prompt. I don't want this prompt.
Solution : replace mvn spring-boot:run with echo y | mvn spring-boot:run

Why do you want this, and why are you breaking your script? This seems like an x-y situation. You have a problem, came up with a solution, now you need help with that solution.

Does the prompt say "stop the program" or does it say "terminate the batch job"?

@u1686_grawity precisely it says "Terminer le programme de commandes (O/N) ?", So yes probably what you are saying would be the right sentence

What's the output of where.exe mvn?

@u1686_grawity it gives :
C:\Users\<myuser>\tools\apache-maven-3.9.6\bin\mvn.cmd```

perhaps you can include your script (batch/powershell/else) in question

The message is not printed by PowerShell – you are running mvn.cmd, a Cmd batch script, and the message is printed by Cmd (the script interpreter) anytime a .cmd or .bat script is Ctrl-C'd.
There is no option to disable the message, other than avoiding the use of .bat/.cmd scripts.

Thanks for the info, it allowed me to find this post : https://superuser.com/questions/35698/how-to-supress-terminate-batch-job-y-n-confirmation where some solutions are shown
